# I am implementing Splash Screen in flutter along with it i am using sharedPreferences I am facing late initialisation error in it

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, setstate, flutter-test

Here I have implemented splash screen and in main.dart I assigned it as home:SplashScreen();
Here I have also implemented sharedPreferences now I am facing late initialisation error for:static late SharedPreferences pref;
I can't understand how resolve it and where to declare pref variable
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
import 'package:onesignal_flutter/onesignal_flutter.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'View/LoginPage.dart';
import 'View/homePageAdmin.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class SharedPrefService {
  static late SharedPreferences pref;

  static Future<void> init() async {
    await SharedPrefService.init();

    SharedPrefService.pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var usrEmail = pref.getString('email');
    String usrname = pref.getString('username').toString();
  }
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  String playerId = '';

  var usrEmail = SharedPrefService.pref.getString('email');
  String usrname = SharedPrefService.pref.getString('username').toString();
  @override
  void initState() async {
    SharedPrefService.pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    super.initState();
    await SharedPrefService.init();

    initPlatformState();

    _navigateToHome();
  }

  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    String usrname = SharedPrefService.pref.getString('username').toString();

    OneSignal.shared.setAppId('e89acaa4-5388-4e3a-bd69-44d197bdcbd7');
    // OneSignal.shared
    //     .promptUserForPushNotificationPermission()
    //     .then((accepted) {});
    final status = await OneSignal.shared.getDeviceState();
    final String? osUserID = status?.userId;
    print('The player id from main.dart ...........${osUserID}');
    // OneSignal.shared.setNotificationOpenedHandler(
    //     (OSNotificationOpenedResult result) async {
    //   var id1 = await result.notification.additionalData!["Docid"];

    //   final int docid = int.parse(id1).toInt();

    //   navigatorKey.currentState!.push(MaterialPageRoute(
    //       builder: (context) => DocumentsDetails(docid, usrname)));
    // });

    setState(() {
      this.playerId = osUserID!;
    });
    print('this.playerid from main.dart ${this.playerId}');
  }

  _navigateToHome() async {
    String pId = this.playerId;

    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1500), () {});
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => usrEmail == null
              ? LoginPage()
              : homePageAdmin(
                  pId,
                  usrname,
                ),
        ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Text(
            'Splash Screen',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.blueAccent),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you use `late` variable before its initialization.

Solution : making `late` variable to `nullable` variable, for example:

```
class SharedPrefService {
  static SharedPreferences? pref; // nullable variable

  static Future<void> init() async {
    await SharedPrefService.init();

    SharedPrefService.pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var usrEmail = pref?.getString('email'); 
    String usrname = pref!.getString('username').toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: So now it will crash with a *different* error message? Does not seem to be the best solution.

Comment: can you share that error message?

Comment: Well, if it's `null` instead of not set, the program wanting to do something with it will still not work, will it?

Comment: @nvoigt you are right but my solution is for get rid of late initialize error.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just make `initState` `async` and expect that to work. Yes, it will be async, but since it is still returning `void`, it cannot be waited on. So, it will be called and then your program will continue without waiting for it.

You seem to have a `Future` and not really an idea how to handle this inside a Flutter widget. I suggest getting a good overview:

[What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

The solution is to use some kind of state management to handle the fact that you are doing something in the background. Your display *cannot* wait for it. It *has* to be displayed. The obvious solution is some kind of spinner or loading screen while you are waiting for the Future to resolve. There is a simple example of a `FutureBuilder` in the link above, or you can use more powerful solutions. Personally, I prefer [bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc), but there are many others, too.